# actionscript (flex): how to know whether a property of object exists (or defined)?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript

I am a Java developer who tries Flex. Here is my problem:

I behave actionScript objects as hashmap but when the object do not have the property it gives exception: No such variable.

Here I expect it gave me null, instead of giving exception. So do you know is there a way to handle it, namely check if the property is defined for object.

trace( obj["2008-02"] )  // gives exception

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Use something along the lines of

```
if (myObject.hasOwnProperty("propertyName"))
```

to check if the property exists.

Edit: Also take a look [here](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/Object.html#hasOwnProperty%28%29).

Answer (score 1):

`hasOwnProperty()` [doesn't work correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6878882/in-actionscript-3-what-is-the-difference-between-the-in-operator-and-the-has#comment35859357_6933895) with inheritance, static properties, or dictionaries.

You should use

```
if ("propertyName" in myObject)
```

instead.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
if ( obj["2008-02"] != null ) { then do something }
```

it is null, but you can't output null.  you can also try converting it to a string for the purposes of a trace().