# In Actionscript 3, what is the difference between the "in" operator and the "hasOwnProperty" method?

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript

The "in" operator and "hasOwnProperty" methods appear to be interchangeable, but I'm wondering if one is checking for inherited properties or something and the other isn't or something like that. I'm especially interested in the case of using it with a Dictionary, but I doubt that is different from other uses.

"hasOwnProperty" is described in the official docs [here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Object.html#hasOwnProperty()) and "in" is described [here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/operators.html#in), but if there is a difference, I didn't find it very clear.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Trusting the preciously accepted answer actually got me into a little bit of trouble. There seems to be more going on than just prototype-related differences. What I've found is that

**hasOwnProperty cannot be used to see if a key is present in a Dictionary when that key is a reference type, but the in operator can.**

Here's an example to demonstrate.

code:

```
var test:Function = function(key:*,label:String):void
    {
        var d:Dictionary = new Dictionary(true);
        d[key] = true;
        trace(label);
        trace("  hasOwnProperty: " + (d.hasOwnProperty(key)?"true":"false <== !!PROBLEM!!"));
        trace("  in: " + (key in d));
        trace("  []: " + d[key]);
    };
test({}, "indexed by object");
test("string", "key is string");
test(0, "key is number");
test(true, "key is boolean");
```

results:

```
indexed by object
  hasOwnProperty: false <== !!PROBLEM!!
  in: true
  []: true
key is string
  hasOwnProperty: true
  in: true
  []: true
key is number
  hasOwnProperty: true
  in: true
  []: true
key is boolean
  hasOwnProperty: true
  in: true
  []: true
```

Comment: And there's more to it still. hasOwnProperty not support static lookup. For example,  `**Static properties**` — variables, constants, or methods defined with the static keyword in an object's defining class or any of its superclasses; and 
`**Prototype properties**` — properties defined on a prototype object that is part of the object's prototype chain. ` will return `false`.

Comment: Another way to look at it is `in` will tell me if it throw an error if I access the property or method where as `hasOwnProperty` will not because it does not check if the static or prototype property or method exist.

Answer (score 4):

The change I know of is `in` looks up the prototype chain while `hasOwnProperty` does not, most AS3 developers don't use prototype, so its not all that relevant for everyday use.